# How do I use variables in a loop with range()? (Python)

Tags: python, variables

I've been searching for quite a while, and I can't seem to find the answer to this. I want to know if you can use variables when using the range() function. For example, I can't get this to work:

```
l=raw_input('Enter Length.')
#Let's say I enter 9.
l=9
for i in range (0,l):
    #Do something (like append to a list)
```

Python tells me I cannot use variables when using the range function. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please post the full traceback...

Comment: If your variable came from `raw_input`, it is a string. Cast it to an `int`.

Comment: @roippi, I agree, but I think that the code we both have in mind is `int(raw_input('Enter Length.'))`, so the exact term is not "Cast", but "Convert it to an integer", or "Construct an integer out of it".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the user inputs is a **string** and you need **integer** values to define the range, you can typecast the input to be a integer value using *int* method.

```
>> l=int(raw_input('Enter Length: '))  # python 3: int(input('Enter Length: '))
>> for i in range (0,l):
>>    #Do something (like append to a list)
```

Comment: `for i in range (l)` is shorter and does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You ask user to input a number

```
l = raw_input('Enter Length: ')
```

But the problem is that entered number will be presented as a **string** instead of int. So you have to convert string 2 int

```
l = int(raw_input('Enter Length: '))
```

If you use Python 2.X you also can optimize your code - instead of range you might use **xrange**. It works much faster.

```
for i in xrange (l):
    #Do something (like append to a list)
```

In Python 3.X xrange was implemented by default

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
x = int(input("the number you want"))
for i in range(x):
```